# What do you call a person that is consistent in her beliefs despite the difficulties they might cause?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I am sure there has to be a more precise word to describe a person that is not giving up on her beliefs no matter what other says. You could say consistent in her beliefs, but I am looking for something more elaborate.

An example of such a person might be Margaret Thatcher.

Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for something like "dogmatic"

Comment: I think choosing Margaret Thatcher as your example is going to bias people's answers to either very laudatory or very negative terms and it's not clear which you want.

Comment: That said, maybe you want "principled," as in a "principled belief."

Comment: Hey, it's a very good idea to wait a couple of hours before accepting an answer. You never know you might get even better suggestions, and answers might earn more upvotes . But if you're really pleased with Kristina's suggestion, that's cool too.

Comment: Hi Mari-Lou, yes, the answer is exactly what I was looking for and as I needed the word quite quickly, I just marked it as accepted. But thanks for the tip, I will be more prudent next time.

Comment: Most of the available options tip your hand by strongly suggesting approval or disapproval of the conduct in a particular case. One relatively neutral term, though, is _doctrinaire_, the adjective form of the noun _doctrinaire_, which means (according to Merriam-Webster) "one who attempts to put into effect an abstract doctrine or theory with little or no regard for practical difficulties."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"...no matter what others say."  Are the "others" right and that person is stubborn, as @Charon offered, or are they ***"resolute"***?

[Resolute](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resolute) as defined by the FreeDictionary.com:

> Firm or determined; unwavering.

Answer (score 3):

[***steadfast***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/steadfast) seems to satisfy your requirements:

> unwavering, as resolution, faith, adherence, etc.

[Google](https://www.google.com/#q=define+steadfast) defines it as "resolutely or dutifully firm and unwavering,"
so, if you like ***resolute***, then you might like this, too.

Answer (score 2):

How about ***[stubborn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stubborn)***?

> having or showing dogged determination not to change one's attitude or position on something, especially in spite of good reasons to do so.
>
> *"you're a silly, stubborn old woman"*

<sub>OED</sub>

Comment: I'm resolute, you're stubborn, he is hidebound.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That one's gone over my head I'm afraid. Is it a quote?

Comment: It's a snowclone (or near); I forget which series of novels it was from. It was called the 'third person singular view of life' or words to that effect. 'I'm well-organised, you're fussy, she's pernickety' / 'I'm cautious, you're timid, he's gutless' ... Essentially, OP needs to add detail, as different answers are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminded me of this passage from *Profiles in Courage* by JFK, and depending on context, **I would say the person is "courageous"**.

> It takes great courage to do what you think is right even though it may mean the end of your career and the dislike and criticism of your friends and neighbors. Many people never have the opportunity to show such courage.  But all of us have the opportunity to recognize such courage in others, to respect the person who is doing what he believes to be right even though we think he is wrong......Courage is much more than bravery on a battlefield; it can mean acting according to your beliefs whatever the consequences......We can all share in such courage by refusing to join with those people who make unreasoning attacks on the man who is doing or saying what he **honestly** believes to be right.
>
> John Fitzgerald Kennedy, Profiles in Courage, Harper & Brothers, New York, 1955.

**I think that adjective fits Baroness Thatcher perfectly.**